# Range of vote percentages in DC in 2012 and 2016 for president?

Tags: united-states, voting, presidential-election, statistics, washington-dc

I want to know the range of two-party votes for the Republican presidential candidate that 95% of precincts fell in. The other 5% has slightly less or more. And, I would like to see a bar graph for 2012 and 2016 Republican vote share by precinct.

I am asking this to see if the vote DC was more evenly distributed in 2016. My ward-level review suggests that the answer is yes. What I mean by "even" is that each precinct would vote about the same way in terms of proportions.

Comment: Not going to downvote, but the question is pretty lazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the precinct-level data provided by the [D.C. Board of Elections](https://electionresults.dcboe.org/), we can find the Republican candidate vote share in the 2012 & 2016 presidential elections. With a bit of manipulation, we can obtain a few statistics about the distributions.

### 2012

Minimum: 0.19% (Precinct 100)
2.5th percentile: 0.35%
Lower quartile: 1.26%
Median: 3.36%
Upper quartile: 11.46%
97.5th percentile: 26.07%
Maximum: 34.98% (Precinct 12)
Mean: 7.02%

### 2016

Minimum: 0.83% (Precinct 100)
2.5th percentile: 1.04%
Lower quartile: 1.84%
Median: 2.84%
Upper quartile: 4.88%
97.5th percentile: 11.31%
Maximum: 15.41% (Precinct 9)
Mean: 3.93%

This data can be presented a bit more nicely in a box plot, as below, which clearly shows a much tighter spread of results across DC precincts.

[image]

This difference can also be illustrated by comparing two bar-graphs, which can be done either visually or on a more numerical basis using the [total variation distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures) of the vote shares with a uniform distribution of votes. A lower measure indicates that the sample is closer to the distribution; in our case, that the vote shares are closer to each other, or as you put it, more evenly distributed. In 2012, this measure is around 446, compared with around 162 in 2016.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The 2012 results are [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_United_States_presidential_election_in_the_District_of_Columbia). Full results by precinct (there are 143 precincts) are [here](https://electionresults.dcboe.org/election_results/2012-General-Election). The approximate breakdown by ward is shown here:

[image]

The 2016 results are [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_United_States_presidential_election_in_the_District_of_Columbia). Full results by precinct (there are 143 precincts) are [here](https://electionresults.dcboe.org/election_results/2016-General-Election). The approximate breakdown by ward is shown here:

[image]

You can use this data to figure it out yourself if you are so inclined.